# How to send data from child to parent in listview

Tags: listview, react-native

Im new to react-native.

What Im doing is sending back the value from child to parent. But it always responds with last value in the array.

Parent code :

```
renderRow: function(currentItem, sectionID, key) {
    var currentSelectedValue = _this.state.selectedValueArray[key];
    return (
        <View
            key={key}
            style={styles.singleItemViewWrapper}
        >
            <SingleItem
                currentKey={key}
                firstName={currentItem.first_name}
                lastName={currentItem.last_name}
                isSelected={currentSelectedValue}
                changeSelected={(currentKey,value) => {
                    var localSelectedValuesArray = [];
                    localSelectedValuesArray = _this.state.selectedValueArray;
                    localSelectedValuesArray[currentKey] = value;
                    _this.setState({ selectedValueArray: localSelectedValuesArray });

                    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
                    _this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(_this.props.route.batches) });
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Child Code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.containerTouchableOpacity}
    onPress={() => {
        _this.props.changeSelected(_this.props.currentKey, !_this.state.isSelectedLocal);
    }}
>
```

There is not any syntactical error. But Im not understanding how to send the clicked item's key to parent. It always sends the last key.

Comment: It's undecipherable. Can you provide a link which reproduces this issue? You can host your app at [rnplay](https://rnplay.org/)

Comment: Sorry so much code linking needs to be done for that, but I can tell you problem in simpler way. 
Im sending 'currentName','firstName' value to child from parent. renderRow as shown in code rendered from array in listView. The data in child view is available but when i call touch event in child and try to send back the variable 'currentKey' to parent again, it always renders last key only. 
Can you help on that ? @Mihir